# Can't filter on terminological codes for ISO 639-2

Tags: sparql, wikidata

On wikidata, with the following query:

```
SELECT ?item ?code
WHERE { ?item wdt:P219 ?code }  # ISO 639-2 code (P219)
```

I find all languages that are defined in ISO 639-2, but for certains languages (for example French), I got 2 different codes (`fra` and `fre`).

This is normal according to ISO 639-2 as it define terminological and bibliographical codes.

Now my question is how do I filter to only get one of them?

I tried to do the following:

```
SELECT ?item ?code
WHERE { ?item wdt:P219 ?code.  # ISO 639-2 code (P219)
        ?code wdt:P518 wd:Q1725664.}  # applies to part (P518), terminology (Q1725664)
```

as mention on the french item (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q150#identifiers)

[image]

but I didn’t get any result.

I suspect it’s because `fre` and `fra` (and thus `?code`) are strings and not item, but I still need a solution to filter on terminological codes.

Comment: Try the `SAMPLE` aggregate function:
`SELECT ?item (SAMPLE(?code) AS ?sample) WHERE {...} GROUP BY ?item`

Comment: It wont work in my case, as I want specifically one of them (terminological) if both are present. (that was not clear in the question, sorry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have two options:
The first one, as in the comment, is to use the sample function. This will work if you don't care whether you use the terminological or bibliographical code.
The query is then:

```
SELECT ?item (SAMPLE(?code) AS ?sampleCode)
WHERE {
?item wdt:P219 ?code
}
GROUP BY ?item
```

If instead you want to choose a particular code, in this case the terminological one, you need to use a similar approach to the one you already had.

```
SELECT ?item ?code
WHERE { ?item p:P219 ?codeStatement.  # ISO 639-2 code (P219)
        ?codeStatement pq:P518 wd:Q1725664 ; # applies to part (P518), terminology (Q1725664)
                       ps:P219 ?code}
```

The difference between the above and your approach lies in the namespaces used. Here I use `p:`, `ps:`, and `pq:`, instead of just `wdt:`.

The difference is that they lead us to a *statement* about a triple.

We use `p:P219` to find all the statements concerning `P219`, and `ps:219` to find the object of those statements.
So:

```
SELECT ?item ?code
WHERE{
?item wdt:P219 ?code}
```

will have the exact same results as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?code
WHERE{
?item p:P219 ?codestatement .
?codestatement ps:P219 ?code.}
```

If we then want to add further restrictions to the statements (e.g. it must only apply to terminology), then we use the `pq:` namespace, together with the appropriate property, in this case `P518`.